# How to order nested model in django DetailView

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.10

I'm learning Django by make Survey program

I made three models, Survey include Questions, and Question include Choices

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Survey(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s : %s" % (self.survey, self.question_text)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.question, self.choice_text)
```

I want to show my result page ordered by votes but now, I just show non-ordered result page.

I think I have to modify my views.py using queryset or extra context. 
but I don't know how to use.

Here is my views and template.

views.py

```
class SurveyResultsView(DetailView):
    model = Survey
    template_name = 'survey/results.html'
```

results.html

```
{% extends 'survey/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<div class="survey-info-container">
  <h1>Results of {{survey.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{survey.description}}</p>
  <p>{{survey.pub_date}}</p>
</div>

<div class="result-container">
  {% for question in survey.question_set.all %}
  <p>
    <h3>{{question.question_text}}</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
          <li>{{choice.choice_text}} -- {{choice.votes}} votes </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul> 
  </p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks for read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can come up with three different ways that you can achieve this.

### Sort in Template

The first, most obvious one is to sort the `choice` objects when you fetch them inside your template. You do this using the `dictsort` filter ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort)) that you apply like I show here below.

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all|dictsort:"votes" %}
    <li>{{choice.choice_text}} -- {{choice.votes}} votes </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Note, there is also a `dictsortreversed` ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#dictsortreversed)) filter that order the objects in reversed order.

### Function on Model

Another way of doing it is defining a function on the `Question` model that returns the entries in the sorted order that you wish for, and then instead of calling `question.choice_set.all()` in your template you would call the function instead.

Example:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    #... 
    def choice_set_sorted(self):
        # Can set .order_by('-votes') to reverse order
        return self.choice_set.all().order_by('votes')
```

Template:

```
{% for choice in question.choice_set_sorted %}
    <li>{{choice.choice_text}} -- {{choice.votes}} votes </li>
{% endfor %}
```

### Setting the Meta class

The third option is to set a default ordering on your Model. If you always want your `Choice` to be ordered by `votes` this could be a good idea.

You do this by setting the `Meta` class in your model with the `ordering` property set to the field that you want to order by ([Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#ordering)).

So the way you would implement this would be:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    #...
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['votes']
```

////

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand !

Comment: If my answer helped you solve the issue, please accept it!

Comment: of course!, but I have 1 problem. I choose <Function on Model> method but my template show nothing. It can't show any choice.

Comment: @kangsan You have to add `self` to the function. So you should write `def choice_set_sorted(self):`